# How to store a PHP variable value into an XML file?

Tags: php, xml

This is my XML file as `conf.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<conf>
  <auth>
     <ids></ids>
     <key></key>
  </auth>
</conf>
```

This is my PHP file as `change.php`

```
<?php   
  $DBUNAME="BOB1";
  $DBPWD="BOB2";  
?>
```

I want that variable `$DBUNAME` and `$DBPWD` gets added into the XML file as an element

```
<ids>BOB1</ids>
<key>BOB2</key>
```

Comment: are you creating xml file using php??

Comment: You need to pick a way to edit XML files and make an edit to do so first.  You should only post specific problems here, not requests for whole solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for your need,

```
<?php 

$file ="config.xml";

$DBUNAME="BOB1";
$DBPWD="BOB2";

//load xml object
$xml= simplexml_load_file($file);

//assign auth id
$xml->auth->ids = $DBUNAME;

//assign auth key
$xml->auth->key = $DBPWD;

//store the value into the file
file_put_contents($file, $xml->asXML());

?>
```